# Callback functions parameters GET requests

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback

Hi I am trying to understand how callback functions work and I have a question that will clear my  doubts. when adding event listeners it is simple

```
$0.addEventListener("click", function(event){console.log(event)});
```

If i perform a "click" the following should happen.

But what about when there is two parameters in the callback function itself. Like in express. What does it mean?

```js
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/page.html")
});
```

Why can't we just say

```js
app.get("/", function(res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/page.html")
});
```

one parameter in the event listener function worked but it does not work here. Why is that? What is the use of the "req", if we are already making a request in with the "/".

Comment: `app.get("/", ...)` doesn't *make* a request, it *registers* your callback to handle a GET request to that endpoint. The callback receives the request and the response objects because *that's the API*, in the same way that the API for an event listener's callback is to receive an event.

Comment: The value of the arguments in the callback are determined by their position, not by their name

Comment: In parameter list, order matters, names don't. The `res` in `(req, res)` is not the `res` in `(res)`

Comment: To illustrate, if you used `function (apple, banana)` you could then use `banana.sendFile(...)` and it would work fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can't skip an argument, because JavaScript refers to an argument by position:

```
app.get("/", function(
  res, // here you would be referring to request
  // actual response can be referenced here
){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/page.html")
});
```

If you don't need a reference to the first argument, the convention is to use an underscore for the name:

```
app.get("/", function(_, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/page.html")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.get("/", function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/page.html")
});
```

The first parameter to the function is `req` and it can contain necessary information such as query string parameters used by the `HTTP GET` request by the user. The second parameter is used to send back the response to caller.

Since you are using the second parameter `res`, you can define the first parameter `req` and ignore it.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use :

```
app.get("/", function({res}){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + "/page.html")
});
```

To understand why it works, you need to understand the implementation of `Express API`.

notice these three interfaces:

```
interface Request<P = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.Request<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
interface RequestHandler<P = core.ParamsDictionary, ResBody = any, ReqBody = any, ReqQuery = core.Query> extends core.RequestHandler<P, ResBody, ReqBody, ReqQuery> { }
interface RequestParamHandler extends core.RequestParamHandler { }
```

They define the `req` handler, and as you can see those interfaces generate an initialization values.

Then, when you don't use `req` it stills works from behind the scene.

So, why using `app.get("/", function({res})` works? because then you keep the default values of `req` by not changing them and notice the compiler that there are few more callback parameters by putting `{}`.

I hope that explanation helped, pretty hard for me the explain that.

Comment: yes it did thank you, but why? I am sorry but I really need to understand this in order to move on.

Comment: Hi, I'm sorry I answered a few days later. Please see edit.